# Gitlab CI reference to another repo

Tags: .net-core, gitlab-ci

I have a .net-core project in a repo 1 that has a reference to another .net-core project in a repo 2. Everything works well in local but I have a job build error when I push project 1:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(285,5):
> error MSB3202: The project file
> "C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\MGzxzeVN\0\Path\To\Project2.csproj" was not
> found. [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\MGzxzeVN\0\Path\To\Project1.sln]

I guess that's normal because Project2 is not in repo 1. But how can I make repo 1 CI find and use project 2 in repo 2 from **master** branch ? I know I should use **.gitlab-ci.yml** file and I have read about cloning the repo with token but it is a little bit confused for me. Is it possible to clone repo 2 and then specify the location where Project 2 can be found instead of using the location in **Project1.sln** when running the pipeline ?

Comment: Have you considered adding second project as a git submodule to the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options,

1. Have two projects in same repo as modules/sub modules
2. Have dependent project binaries published and refer from current project via Nuget or any other means (similar to maven dependency in java)
3. clone project in pipeline

For 3rd method, you need to have `git` installed your build image. Then create a token from gitlab and use it as follows to clone the repo.

```
git clone https://{deploy-key-name}:{deploy-key-token}@gitlab.mydomain.com/my-group/my-project-name.git
```

The path is relative to your build directory, so make sure its properly referenced in you project

I would prefer 2nd method if possible.

reference: https://blog.programster.org/gitlab-create-a-projects-access-token

Comment: I have decided to use sub modules for now and it works well, but I will use NuGet at the end. Thanks.